# How to reconcile two different IDs as one, then apply to a df with both IDs but count the subject only once in R?

Tags: r, join, data-wrangling

I have two different IDs for the same subject(patient).
In this other vector of IDs, the two IDs are both in there that indicate the same patient. How do I only count the patient once(by ID1), instead of two different patients with different IDs?

```
ID1 ID2 
 11 12
 13 14
 15 16
```

vector

```
11,12,13,13,14,16
```

I want to count only the unique patients by ID1, such that I would get

```
x=11,13,15
```

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 11, 13, 16 ?

Comment: No, going by ID1

Comment: Then why do you need `vector` at all? It would be just `df$ID1` ? If that is not what you want maybe provide a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think probably you need this

```
df %>% filter((ID1 %in% vector) | (ID2 %in% vector)) %>%
   select(ID1)

  ID1
1  11
2  13
3  15
```

Check it on a better sample

```
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L), ID2 = c(12L, 
14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 22L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)

> df
  ID1 ID2
1  11  12
2  13  14
3  15  16
4  17  18
5  19  20
6  21  22


vector <- c(11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16, 18, 18)

> df %>% filter((ID1 %in% vector) | (ID2 %in% vector)) %>% select(ID1)
  
   ID1
1  11
2  13
3  15
4  17
```

By slightly modifying Ronak's code, you can get same results

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(ID1, ID2)) %>%
  inner_join(tibble::enframe(vector), by = 'value') %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = T) %>%
  select(ID, value) %>%
  inner_join(df %>% mutate(ID = row_number()), by = 'ID') %>%
  select(ID1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique `ID` number for each patient, get the data in long format so both the ID's are in same column, join it with the vector select vector values for distinct `ID` values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(ID1, ID2)) %>%
  inner_join(tibble::enframe(vector), by = 'value') %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(value)

#  value
#  <dbl>
#1    11
#2    13
#3    16
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(11L, 13L, 15L), ID2 = c(12L, 14L, 16L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
vector <- c(11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 16)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants results from `ID1` only.  Please see slight modification in your code, at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` with `%in%` by selecting the rows with `apply` to subset `ID1`.

```
ID$ID1[apply(ID, 1, function(z) any(v %in% z))]
#[1] 11 13 15
```

or use `rowSums`.

```
ID$ID1[rowSums(sapply(ID, "%in%", v)) > 0]
#[1] 11 13 15
```

Data:

```
ID <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ID1 ID2 
 11 12
 13 14
 15 16")
v <- c(11,12,13,13,14,16)
```